# How preferred is Kafka in Applications in terms of processing time without having Filters as in JMS selectors.

Tags: apache-kafka, activemq-classic

1. Kafka does not have any concept of filters at the brokers that can ensure – messages that are being picked up by a consumer matches some criteria. The filtering has to happen at the consumers (or applications). - *So in this case there is an increase in the processing time at the client/consumer.*
2. In the case of JMS – if your messaging application needs to filter the messages it receives, you can use a JMS API message selector, which allows a message consumer to specify the messages it is interested in. Message selectors assign the work of filtering messages to the JMS provider rather than to the application. - *So in this case there is an increase in the processing time at the JMS provider*

Which of the above two proves to be better in terms of keeping the code clean and improving performance too?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your question can be answered conclusively as the performance will ultimately depend on the actual implementation (i.e. which specific JMS provider is used) as well as the particular use-case (e.g. details like the number of clients, the message volume, how many messages match the filters, network speed, etc.).